# Drupal - embedding/updating View pages with AJAX

Tags: ajax, drupal, view

I've been scratching my head like crazy over this all day, there seems to be a hundred different ways to get what I want done but I want it done a certain way - which I can't find.

Here's what I'm working on: http://schmidtbrotherscutlery.com/dev/mySchmidt/myCutlery/

My setup is one view with four different pages, each filtered by category. Default page above lists all three categories at once, and the Category sublinks in the menu take you to the three other view pages that are filtered by a single category. What I need is each of the category sublinks to load their respective view pages with AJAX instead of page by page refresh like it is now. I realize I can effectively achieve the same thing with an exposed filter on the categories but I want these specific menu sublinks to load the view pages, not filter one view on it's own with an exposed form. This really doesn't seem to be that difficult and I don't know why I haven't been able to figure it out yet but I don't have much experience with Drupal+AJAX integration. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read it sounds like you should be able to put each of the views within a jQuery tab container. So for example:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div class="tab">
    <?php views_embed_view('viewname', 'block_1')?>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
    <?php views_embed_view('viewname', 'block_2')?>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
    <?php views_embed_view('viewname', 'block_3')?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This would allow you to cycle through each content piece without refreshing the page.